FAILURE: Build failed with an exception when adding dependencies
I have a problem when i'm adding sqflit in dependencies in pubspec.yaml and click run and debug it's give me this error :
Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone64 x86 64 in debug mode...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':sqflite_android:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
 Could not resolve all files for configuration ':sqflite_android:androidJdkImage'.
   > Failed to transform core-for-system-modules.jar to match attributes {artifactType=_internal_android_jdk_image, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Execution failed for JdkImageTransform: C:\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-34\core-for-system-modules.jar.
         > Error while executing process C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio1\jbr\bin\jlink.exe with arguments {--module-path C:\Users\Hossam Hassan\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\4a46fc89ed5f9adfe3afebf74eb8bfeb\transformed\output\temp\jmod --add-modules java.base --output C:\Users\Hossam Hassan\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\4a46fc89ed5f9adfe3afebf74eb8bfeb\transformed\output\jdkImage --disable-plugin system-modules}

* Try:
 Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
 Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
 Run with --scan to get full insights.
 Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

BUILD FAILED in 3s
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Exited (1).


and that's what in pubspec.yaml
name: todo
description: "A new Flutter project."
# The following line prevents the package from being accidentally published to
# pub.dev using `flutter pub publish`. This is preferred for private packages.
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number is used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
# In Windows, build-name is used as the major, minor, and patch parts
# of the product and file versions while build-number is used as the build suffix.
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ^3.5.4

# Dependencies specify other packages that your package needs in order to work.
# To automatically upgrade your package dependencies to the latest versions
# consider running `flutter pub upgrade --major-versions`. Alternatively,
# dependencies can be manually updated by changing the version numbers below to
# the latest version available on pub.dev. To see which dependencies have newer
# versions available, run `flutter pub outdated`.
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.8
  sqflite: ^2.4.1
  intl: ^0.20.0

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  # The "flutter_lints" package below contains a set of recommended lints to
  # encourage good coding practices. The lint set provided by the package is
  # activated in the `analysis_options.yaml` file located at the root of your
  # package. See that file for information about deactivating specific lint
  # rules and activating additional ones.
  flutter_lints: ^4.0.0

# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter packages.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  # assets:
  #   - images/a_dot_burr.jpeg
  #   - images/a_dot_ham.jpeg

  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.dev/to/resolution-aware-images

  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.dev/to/asset-from-package

  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  # fonts:
  #   - family: Schyler
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Regular.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
  #         style: italic
  #   - family: Trajan Pro
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.dev/to/font-from-package



it's just showing when sqflit was available put if I delete it, it's working without any problem and this sqflit link
When I delete sqflit dependencies it's run without any problem

Can you please check your java version by executing this command in your terminal or cmd java --version?

I am able to use the sqflite plugin with Java 17. So please check which Java SDK you're using.
